# can someone help me fix this script?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
const config = require("./config.json"); 

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member =>{
  var role = member.guild.roles.find("ID", "here I put the role id");
  member.addRole(role);    
});
```

This script is giving error and I don't know how to fix it. The error is:

> member.guild.roles.find is not a function

Answer (score 1):

`discord.js` v12+ uses `Managers`, so you will have to add the cache property.

Replace:

```js
var role = member.guild.roles.find("ID", "here I put the role id");
```

with:

```js
var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === 'ID Here')
```

---

An even easier way to do it is with the `.get()` method:

```js
var role = member.guild.roles.cache.get("ID Here")
```

Although either would work.

---

Since `discord.js` v12+, the `addRole()` method is *also* deprecated. Instead, replace it with:

```js
member.roles.add(role)
```

Comment: Hey just saying `GuildMember.roles.cache.add` is not valid; it is just `GuildMember.roles.add`. View the [official Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-add-a-role-to-a-guild-member) to clarify your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading on the Discord.js v12 docs regarding adding roles to members [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add)

> Things in the cache are now found directly on the cache

and members/roles/users/channels are all found on the cache, sooo

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
const config = require("./config.json"); 

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member =>{
  var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "ROLE ID HERE");
  member.roles.add(role.id);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Joaozwy (Brazilian like me or not? :)

First things first. Why you are receiving this error?

The event [`"guildMemberAdd"`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) from [`Discord.Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) send the [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object as a parameter.

It has the [`guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=guild) property which has the property [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles).

But `member.guild.roles` which is from type [`RoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager) doesn't have the method `find`.

That's why it's giving you the error you are receiving.

Now, It seems to me, with the available information you gave us, you are trying to get the role by it's `ID` and add to the `member`.
If that's the case, try this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
const config = require("./config.json"); 

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member =>{
  let role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === "here I put the role id");
  member.roles.add(role, "Optional string saying why are you adding this role to the member");
});
```

Remember to change the string `"here I put the role id"` to the string with the correct role ID you wanna add to the user.

Also, the add method returns a `Promise`. Its a good practice to, at least, listen for errors or rejections on promises so if something goes wrong, you can know why.

Comment: You'll need to add the cache property to `member.roles.add()` for it to work. `member.roles.cache.add()`

Comment: @Lioness100 I think `member.roles.add` works without the cache property - how can a role which the member does not have be cached as the role which the member has?

Comment: @Lioness100 I recommend you read this guide to clarify your understanding: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-add-a-role-to-a-guild-member